# Why isn't the Sandbox Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, sandbox

We all know and love [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/5162#5162). It's one of our best features. But in the body of the Sandbox, I noticed this:

> This is a community-maintained list of the most active Sandbox submissions, sorted by major contest type. Add an entry to the top of this list if you add a new submission or update an old one. If you don't have enough reputation to edit questions you can ask in chat for a higher-rep user to add your submission for you. You may include a [status] indicator and tags to categorize your submission.

This means that you can edit to update your submission, or ask someone to do it for you. But if the goal is to have the community keep it maintained, then why isn't it a community wiki question, which would allow people with 100+ rep to edit it, rather than needing 1000+? If the problem is vandals, you would still need 100 rep, meaning that people trust you enough. The answers being CW as well would mean that it would both be better for a testing ground, as you would not gain or lose rep for good or bad ideas (which I don't think happens anyway), and that the answers could be deleted a week after posting, which means that we wouldn't have so much clutter from posted answers from a long time ago. And even if something bad does happen, rollbacks can fix posts that have been vandalized, and we already punish things like that.
There appear to be a lot of upsides to making this CW. So why isn't it a community wiki question?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that all answers to CW questions are automatically also CW. However, that might not be a problem in this case (or maybe even a good thing?). At the same time, I'm personally not a fan of that list at all, because it's always out of date, costs a lot of vertical space and I don't even know if anyone actually uses it.

Comment: I only use it to find my own answers. For anything else I just browse sorted by active.

Comment: @trichoplax [you could also use this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+inquestion%3A2140) (I'm happy to put that link in the sandbox)

Comment: @MartinBüttner that's brilliant. That would be a great link to have in the sandbox whether we keep the other lists or not.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies [You almost did](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/2140/161). ;)

Answer (score 9):

## No.

Now that [the sandbox list is gone](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5178/getting-rid-of-the-sandbox-directory) (probably for good), there is no reason for sandbox to be a CW as no one would want to edit it that often.

Benefits of making Sandbox CW:

- Lowered threshold of 100 instead of 1000 rep to edit the directory list (which is gone now)

  - Commenting requires 50 rep, so if any new person wanted to edit a proposal, he can anyways leave a comment (assuming he has at least 100 rep which was required to edit the proposal).

Negatives:

- Users who have proposed challenges in sandbox loose their icons/identicons/gravatar images, **even their names**.

I'd say that *now* there is no real need to make Sandbox a CW.

Comment: What exactly is the benefit of having the profile pictures in the answers? Also, I think it's a good thing that sandbox proposals now don't count towards the [meta-tag:discussion] tag badge. Furthermore, being able to edit below 1000 rep is a very good thing. No one will leave comments to point out simple typos they noticed when proofreading - but if they can just quickly edit them out, it's much more likely they'll get fixed.

Comment: Profile pictures bring familiarity to the proposals. If the only reason we are making sandbox CW is so that typos can be fixed, then sorry, I am even more against it. Again, any other kind of edit should anyways not be made by a newbie directly and should be relayed through comments only.

Comment: Will comments on my sandbox answer show up in my notifications now that my answer is CW? That's my main concern, especially if we are using comment notification to check if old answers are eligible for being adopted by someone else.

Comment: I can confirm that a comment left on my sandbox answer does show up in my notifications (thanks @MartinBüttner ).

Comment: I have reverted the community wiki status on the sandbox and all answers (after Chris casually implemented [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256059/201409)).

Comment: I've changed my vote now that the [sandbox may move to main](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/move-the-sandbox-to-main) as I don't want this to be a reason to avoid moving to main.

Comment: @trichoplax your argument does not make any sense. Making sandbox CW will still hide user profile pics, be it on main or here. (And on both places, it won't be edited that much)

Comment: @Optimizer my point is that I only object to losing the username and avatar when there is no reason to. Now that the sandbox may be on main, there is a strong reason to make that small sacrifice - so that rep on the sandbox doesn't cause conflict and discourage people from deleting.

Comment: Maybe we need a new meta question about making the sandbox on main CW?

Comment: I've made a new [meta post about making CW to move to main](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/if-the-sandbox-was-on-main-would-you-support-it-being-community-wiki).

Answer (score 4):

*I'm speaking as a user, not a moderator.*

Making the Sandbox CW also makes all its answers CW. On meta, the only effect is to lower the rep threshold for editing anything too 100 (the answers also don't count towards tag badges any longer, but they aren't meant to be permanent anyway). I think that's a good thing, because I've quite often seen that users below 1k rep wanted to suggest (helpful) edits to sandbox proposals but couldn't. So:

**I'm in favour of making the sandbox a community wiki.** Mostly for the effect on the answers.

However, I am not a fan of the list itself and would prefer to see it removed. [This can be discussed over here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5178/8478)

[Note that the [Meta rep requirements have been removed since this was posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/should-we-remove-the-reputation-requirement-for-answering-on-meta).]

Comment: I am in favor of this if the Sandbox is [put on Main](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7478/26997).