# Community is being Overprotective of the Sandbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sandbox, protected-questions

Recently @Community♦︎ has been constantly [protecting](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2140/revisions) our beloved Sandbox.

[image]

Our [rep threshold](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7084/40695) for meta has been decreased specifically to grant new users access to the Sandbox so they can post their proposed challenges. Having the Sandbox protected, conflicts this raising the rep requirement up to +10 to post an answer.

It seems that because of some new users [deleting their / posing new sandbox posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238929/204010) or some other reason, @Community is assuming the Sandbox is attracting bad quality answers.

---

Can the sandbox's auto-protection somehow be disabled or at least the threshold for auto-protection be changed? I don't know if this is possible, but I can ask nicely :3

Comment: Nice freehand, uh, err rectangle. :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've disabled auto-protection on this meta site.

Or rather, set the relevant thresholds (answers from new users) to 10,000.

That should keep things under control for a few weeks.

Comment: Hopefully "_a few weeks_" means [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/308256).